# Yahoo Finance indexes using dirkolbrich/yahoo-finance-query library

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a couple of selects for asia and canada indexes, with the correct value for them (which I've taken from [enter link description here](https://in.finance.yahoo.com/intlindices?e=asia))

,like so :

```
<select name="symbols[]">
     <option label="Straits Times" value="^STI">Straits Times</option>
</select>
```

So I use this [library](https://github.com/dirkolbrich/yahoo-finance-query) and I use the following method to get the data:

```
function getYahooIndexes($params)
{

    $query = new YahooFinanceQuery;
    $symbol = $params["symbols"];
    $data = $query->indexList($symbol)->get();
    return $data;
}
```

I get an array with the values I have selected but it contains no information about those:

```
 ["data"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#234 (2) {
      ["symbol"]=>
      string(7) "^GSPTSE"
      ["components"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#240 (2) {
      ["symbol"]=>
      string(8) "CADUSD=X"
      ["components"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
```

I used the method he suggested:

```
indexList(array $symbol)

Query for an index which returns the symbol and name of the components. Several symbols may be passed as an array.

See http://finance.yahoo.com/intlindices?e=europe for more symbols to world indices. The caret ^ character must be part of the symbol.

$symbol = array('^GDAXI');
$data = $query->indexList($symbol)->get();
```

In the source code the indexList method looks like this:

```
/**
 * get list of component for indices symbol from yahoo.finance.com
 *
 * @param array $symbol
 */
public function indexList(array $symbols)
{
    $query = new IndexList($this->yql);
    $this->query = $query->query($symbols);
    return $this;
}
```

I am a beginner in back-end development so If I didn't explain it too well I am sorry I will try to give you the details you will require. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why not post this on the project in github?

Comment: I tried but I got no response and I have to find a solution fast